# Prioritize By Values Within Group

Tags: mysql, group-by

In MySQL, say I have the following table (called `workers`):

```
| id | specialty | status     | name
| :- | :-------- | :--------- | :--- |
| 1  | Bricks    | Unemployed | Joe
| 2  | Bricks    | Employed   | Eric
| 3  | Bricks    | Contracted | Bob
| 4  | Tiles     | Employed   | Dylan
| 5  | Tiles     | Contracted | James
```

In my query, say I want to find who is a prospective person for a new job. Thus, I would want to first find who is `Unemployed`, if no one is `Unemployed`, then who is only `Contracted`, and if no one is `Contracted` then at least who is `Employed`.

This would be `GROUP BY` `specialty`. The only methods I could figure out are either complex sub-queries or sets of `UNION`s (or both). I also tried `GROUP_CONCAT` however this didn't work (or I didn't do it right). Googling this has not yielded any results.

Another idea is to assign a value to each category, and then do a `group-wise max/min` sub-query. I piloted this and it works, however seems quite messy and definitely not normalized:

```sql
SELECT
    `id`,
    `name`,
    `status`,
    -- I haven't been able to figure out how to get rid of MIN from the actual select
    -- statement except by wrapping this in another sub-query, which I'm not keen on
    MIN(`priority`) AS `priority`
FROM workers
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 'Unemployed' AS `status`, 0 AS `priority` FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 'Contracted' AS `status`, 1 AS `priority` FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 'Employed'   AS `status`, 2 AS `priority` FROM dual
) AS priorities USING (`status`)
GROUP BY `specialty`;
```

I am looking for a more standard, efficient, normalized or versatile method of doing this.

#### Update:

An additional method I could be to use a `CASE` expression in the `SELECT` clause of the statement. This would be if I were to normalize the `status` column, through a foreign-key relationship or other related table:

New table called `statuses`

```
| id | status         |
| :- | :------------- | 
| 1  | Employed       |
| 2  | Contracted     |
| 3  | Unemployed     |
| 4  | Not contracted |
```

> **Diffs:** `'Not Contracted'` is a new status and my `workers` table now stores the foreign key to the new statuses table.

Then my SQL would be:

```sql
SELECT
    `id`,
    `name`,
    statuses.status,
    MIN(`priority`) AS `priority`
FROM workers
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        `id`,
        `status`,
        CASE
            -- currently uses text in `status`,
            -- could also explicitly use `id`
            WHEN `status` IN ('Unemployed', 'Not Contracted') THEN 0
            WHEN `status` = 'Contracted' THEN 1
            WHEN `status` = 'Employed' THEN 2
            ELSE 3
        END AS `priority`
    FROM statuses
) AS statuses ON workers.status = statuses.id
GROUP BY `specialty`;
```

> **Note:** You might think - why not put the `priority` in the statuses table? The reason why I am not doing that is because the priority changes depending on the data needed / the purpose of the report being generated.

Potentially this is a cleaner solution (for the times that the related data to prioritize against is in another table). Again, I am looking for a more standard, efficient, normalized or versatile method of doing this. Also, if there is more of a way this could be configurable to user input / variables.

Comment: There is no avoiding introducing a `CASE` expression unless you want to include a status table.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty here mainly arises because you don't have an ordinal column which ranks the various status in some order.  Absent that, we can introduce one using a `CASE` expression, similar to what your second query is trying to do:

```
SELECT w1.*
FROM workers w1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        specialty,
        MIN(CASE status WHEN 'Unemployed' THEN 1
                        WHEN 'Contracted' THEN 2
                        ELSE 3 END) AS status_rnk
    FROM workers
    GROUP BY specialty
) w2
    ON w1.specialty = w2.specialty AND
       w2.status_rnk = CASE w1.status WHEN 'Unemployed' THEN 1
                                      WHEN 'Contracted' THEN 2
                                      ELSE 3 END;
```